# JSON Stringify Ouput to Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a simple JS app that takes in a JSON file, displays the information to the user and allows them to modify it, and then allows them to re-export the JSON. However, the JSON that is being brought in is multi-line; each key/value is on its own line. When I use `.stringify` to output the JSON, it all appears on one line. Is there any way for the stringify method to separate the lines?

JSON Structure:

```
{"Title":
 {"lvlOne":[
  {"key":"val"},
  {"key":"val"},
  {"key":"val"}
 ],
 "lvl2":[
  {"key":"val"},
  {"key":"val"},
  {"key":"val"}
 ]}
}
```

But when I output, it all shows:

```
{"Title":{"lvlOne":[{"key":"val"},{"key":"val"},{"key":"val"}],"lvl2":[{"key":"val"{"key":"val"},{"key":"val"}]}}
```

Comment: Please research `JSON.stringify`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify - a third parameter can be used to specify the spacing for pretty printing

Comment: Where do you print this output ?

Comment: I populate a `<textarea>` with the JSON for the user to copy and deploy.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the `space` parameter of the [stringify method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).  From the official page, here is the relevant excerpt:

```
JSON.stringify({ a: 2 }, null, " ");   // '{\n "a": 2\n}'
```

Comment: why " " helps to add a new line instead of just a space ?

Answer (score 10):

you can also use.

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ uno: 1, dos : {"s":"dd","t":"tt"} }, null, '\t');
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 8):

Or even better, the count of spaces in the indentation:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ uno: 1, dos : {"s":"dd","t":"tt"} }, null, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the above worked for me the only thing that worked for me was

```
await fs.promises.writeFile('testdataattr.json',JSON.stringify(datatofile, null,'\r\n'),'utf8') ;
```